# AngularJS: orderBy - string & array are not the same

Tags: angularjs, multiple-columns, angularjs-orderby

I have an array of users:

```
$scope.users = [
  {name: 'Anh', age: 10},
  {name: 'Ánh', age: 10},
  {name: 'Ba' , age: 10}
]
```

When i use `orderBy:'name'` the result is:

1. Anh
2. Ánh
3. Ba

but when i use multiple fields `orderBy:['name','age']` the result is different:

1. Anh
2. Ba
3. Ánh

Waiting for your help!

Comment: Please provide a plunkr. I'm getting the same result for both: [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/rHlhqBPwcbsrHvCRqN1a?p=preview)

Comment: Are you sure you're using `orderBy:'name'`, and not `orderBy:name`? Looks like in the first case the array isn't reordered at all.

Comment: Seems ok for me http://plnkr.co/edit/10o7x0ZemlDUW7rEan6B?p=preview

Comment: Thanks, `orderBy:'name'` is correct, but how i can sort the list with unicode characters like:
- Anh.
- Ánh.
- Ba.

I can do this in mysql db using utf8 collation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this..

```
var app = angular.module('filterSample', []);
app.controller('filterCtrl', function ($scope) {

  $scope.data = {
    messages: ['first', 'second', '3rd', 'fourth', 'fifth']
  }

  $scope.startsWith = function (actual, expected) {
    var lowerStr = (actual + "").toLowerCase();
    return lowerStr.indexOf(expected.toLowerCase()) === 0;
  }
});
```

and html as

```
<ul border="1px" ng-repeat="msg in data.messages | filter:search:startsWith">
      <li>{{msg}}</li>
    </ul>
```

or check on this plunkr-http://plnkr.co/edit/gcVYfZXTqsDU1Z7REU2I?p=preview